# TLS handshake failed with error remote error: tls: bad certificate server=Orderer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to set up a hyperledger fabric on a VM manually. I have generated all the artifacts and configured the `orderer.yaml` and `core.yaml`. I have orderer running on port `127.0.0.1:7050`. When I try to create channel using the peer cli `channel create` command I am getting a `context deadline exceeded` message on peer terminal.

```
./bin/peer channel create -o 127.0.0.1:7050 -c $CHANNEL_NAME -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls --cafile /home/fabric-release/mynetwork/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
```

> Error: failed to create deliver client: orderer client failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:7050: failed to create new connection: context deadline exceeded

On the orderer terminal I am getting the following error:

> 2019-04-23 09:22:03.707 EDT [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 01b TLS handshake failed with error remote error: tls: bad certificate server=Orderer remoteaddress=127.0.0.1:38618
>
> 2019-04-23 09:22:04.699 EDT [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 01c TLS handshake failed with error remote error: tls: bad certificate server=Orderer remoteaddress=127.0.0.1:38620
>
> 2019-04-23 09:22:06.187 EDT [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 01d TLS handshake failed with error remote error: tls: bad certificate server=Orderer remoteaddress=127.0.0.1:38622

I have gone through the configurations a few time, I am not sure if I am missing something. Following is my `orderer.yaml`

```
General:
  LedgerType: file
  ListenAddress: 127.0.0.1
  ListenPort: 7050

  TLS:
    Enabled: true
    PrivateKey: /home/fabric-release/mynetwork/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/server.key
    Certificate: /home/fabric-release/mynetwork/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/server.crt
    RootCAs:
      - /home/fabric-release/mynetwork/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/ca.crt
    ClientAuthRequired: true

  Keepalive:
    ServerMinInterval: 60s
    ServerInterval: 7200s
    ServerTimeout: 20s

  GenesisMethod: file

  GenesisProfile: OneOrgOrdererGenesis

  GenesisFile: channel-artifacts/genesis.block

  LocalMSPDIR: /home/fabric-release/mynetwork/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp

  LocalMSPID: OrdererMSP

  Authentication:
    TimeWindow: 15m

FileLedger:
  Location: /var/hyperledger/production/orderer
  Prefix: hyperledger-fabric-ordererledger
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue is that the TLS server certificate used by the orderer does not have a SAN matching "127.0.0.1".  You can add "localhost" and/or "127.0.0.1" to you TLS certificates by using a custom **crypto-config.yaml** when generating your artifacts with cryptogen:

```
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# "OrdererOrgs" - Definition of organizations managing orderer nodes
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OrdererOrgs:
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Orderer
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  - Name: Orderer
    Domain: example.com
    EnableNodeOUs: false

    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # "Specs" - See PeerOrgs below for complete description
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Specs:
      - Hostname: orderer
        SANS:
          - "localhost"
          - "127.0.0.1"

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# "PeerOrgs" - Definition of organizations managing peer nodes
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PeerOrgs:
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Org1
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  - Name: org1
    Domain: org1.example.com
    EnableNodeOUs: true
    Template:
      Count: 2
      SANS:
         - "localhost"
         - "127.0.0.1"
    Users:
      Count: 1

  - Name: org2
    Domain: org2.example.com
    EnableNodeOUs: false
    Template:
      Count: 2
      SANS:
         - "localhost"
         - "127.0.0.1"
    Users:
      Count: 1
```

Comment: awesome - glad to hear it

Comment: I still facing the same error even if the config changed as per the answer

Comment: @GariSingh I am getting the same error logs in the orderer... I am using fabric-ca to generate certificates. The network runs fine for Non TLS network. Can you please help ?

Comment: Might be best to create a new post with the details of your setup and your error(s)

Answer (score 2):

I also faced the same problem and in my case, the issue was that I made some changes to the local directory files and apparently those changes were not successfully reflected while mounting those files back into the docker containers. What fixed the problem for me was

`docker volume rm $(docker volume ls)`

I restarted the network again and didn't see any more certificate errors. Worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

when the problem of TLS handshake failed occurs between the orderer and orderer, it is most likely that there is an error in the configuration parameters when generating the TLS file.

if you are registered with TLS via fabric-ca, then you need to check whether the CSR properties in the TLS files of the two orderer are the same. You can use the following command "openssl x509 -in certificate.crt -text -noout".

The following you need to check whether the --cer.names, -m and other parameters of the orderer enroll are duplicate or incorrect.

In cases where the contents of the TLS file are consistent and the HostName specified, it is rare for the handshake to fail