# Hyperledger Fabric with TLS enable

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Did anyone try to setup a Hyperledger Fabric with TLS enable on different machines? (As I did not find any tutorial or sample regarding the TLS configuration).

Is it docker swarm is a MUST for this kind of network configuration?

As currently when I tried to deploy multiple hyperledger fabric orderer nodes on different machines with TLS enabled. I keep encountering the following

2019-10-07 09:31:50.470 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 549 TLS handshake failed with error remote error: tls: bad certificate server=Orderer remoteaddress=192.168.50.79:54992

I found something similar on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55803125/tls-handshake-failed-with-error-remote-error-tls-bad-certificate-server-ordere) but the same error still keep prompt out in the log files. Did anyone get any clues on this?

Thanks

Comment: to run Hyperledger fabric on multiple machines you need docker swarm cluster, follow this tutorial https://medium.com/@wahabjawed/hyperledger-fabric-on-multiple-hosts-a33b08ef24f

Comment: @mohammedrampurawala thanks for your comment. I read the tutorial that shared by you but the example in the tutorial, the TSL setting is been disabled. However, for my case, I need to enable the TSL setting but once I enabled it, then I will see the error log as I mentioned in my post :(

Answer (score 0):

To run hyperledger fabric on multiple machines you can just use docker with local containers. The config is not straight forward but I've been constructing a `connection-profile.yaml` and can confirm it works as I now have it running.

The setup is not exactly straight-forward but its doable.