# Hyperledger fabric:TLS handshake failed with error remote error: tls: bad certificate server=Orderer remoteaddress

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

This seems like a common issue in HLF channel creation command

Here is my command to create the channel

```
peer channel create -o orderer1.workspace:7050 -c base-main-channel -f ./config/channel.tx --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/base.order/orderers/orderer1.base.order/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.base.order-cert.pem
```

The error I am getting from the order node is

```
ERRO 02d TLS handshake failed with error remote error: tls: bad certificate server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.23.0.7:36982
```

I've tried the solution from this question [TLS handshake failed with error remote error: tls: bad certificate server=Orderer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55803125/tls-handshake-failed-with-error-remote-error-tls-bad-certificate-server-ordere)

But it doesn't work for me

The only difference I am using `raft` ordering service instead of `kafka`

Here is my raft config

```
Raft:
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Capabilities:
            <<: *ChannelCapabilities
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            OrdererType: etcdraft
            EtcdRaft:
                Consenters:
                - Host: orderer.base
                  Port: 7050
                  ClientTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/base.order/orderers/orderer1.base.order/tls/server.crt
                  ServerTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/base.order/orderers/orderer1.base.order/tls/server.crt
            Addresses:
                - orderer.base:7050
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the uncorrect folder path for **--cafile** in your `peer channel create` command.

Instead of

```
--cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/base.order/orderers/orderer1.base.order/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.base.order-cert.pem
```

Use

```
--cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/base.order/tlsca/tlsca.base.order-cert.pem
```

Comment: you are only using one orderer? Cause the minimum amount of orderers for Raft is 3.

Comment: Yes only one orderer

Comment: Then you are not doing it right. Please read the documentation. The minimum amount of orderers for Raft is 3. If you want to run 1 orderer only, your configuration should be *solo*

Comment: np. Please remember to set this as answer so we can close the issue.

Comment: Now I got another error `Failed to send StepRequest to 3, because: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = all SubConns are in TransientFailure, latest connection error: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 172.25.0.7:9050: connect: connection refused" channel=basechannel node=2`

Comment: This is because you have set uncorrectly the way to connect each other with orderers. I would be happy to help but not in this question. Please, mark my answer as **answer** so that we close this issue. Open a new one if you have connection problems between your Raft orderers and I will answer there. Best regards

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206443/discussion-between-iam-batman-and-ricntt).

Comment: @RicNitt here is it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59860326/hyperledger-fabrictransport-authentication-handshake-failed-x509-certificate

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to  remove the container's volumes

```
docker volume rm $(docker volume ls)
```

and restart the network