# Hyperledger fabric:transport: authentication handshake failed: x509: certificate on channel create

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to create a channel in HLF using the following command

```
peer channel create -o orderer1.base:7050 -c basechannel -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/base.order/tlsca/tlsca.base.order-cert.pem
```

But it's failing due to this error

> Failed to send StepRequest to 2, because: rpc error: code =
>   Unavailable desc = all SubConns are in TransientFailure, latest
>   connection error: connection error: desc = "transport: authentication
>   handshake failed: x509: certificate is valid for orderer2.base.order,
>   orderer2, not orderer2.base" channel=basechannel node=1
>
> Failed to send StepRequest to 3, because: rpc error: code =
>   Unavailable desc = all SubConns are in TransientFailure, latest
>   connection error: connection error: desc = "transport: authentication
>   handshake failed: x509: certificate is valid for orderer3.base.order,
>   orderer3, not orderer3.base" channel=basechannel node=1

Here is the raft config in `configtx.yaml`

```
Raft:
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Capabilities:
            <<: *ChannelCapabilities
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            OrdererType: etcdraft
            EtcdRaft:
                Consenters:
                - Host: orderer1.base
                  Port: 7050
                  ClientTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/base.order/orderers/orderer1.base.order/tls/server.crt
                  ServerTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/base.order/orderers/orderer1.base.order/tls/server.crt
                - Host: orderer2.base
                  Port: 8050
                  ClientTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/base.order/orderers/orderer2.base.order/tls/server.crt
                  ServerTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/base.order/orderers/orderer2.base.order/tls/server.crt
                - Host: orderer3.base
                  Port: 9050
                  ClientTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/base.order/orderers/orderer3.base.order/tls/server.crt
                  ServerTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/base.order/orderers/orderer3.base.order/tls/server.crt
            Addresses:
                - orderer1.base:7050
                - orderer2.base:8050
                - orderer3.base:9050
```

Container configuration in `docker-compose.yaml`

```
orderer1.base:
    extends:
      file: base.yaml
      service: orderer-base
    container_name: orderer1.base
    environment:
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENPORT=7050
    networks:
    - byfn
    volumes:
        - ./artifacts/genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
        - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/base.order/orderers/orderer1.base.order/msp:/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
        - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/base.order/orderers/orderer1.base.order/tls:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls
        - orderer1.base.order:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer
    ports:
    - 7050:7050
  orderer2.base:
    extends:
      file: base.yaml
      service: orderer-base
    container_name: orderer2.base
    environment:
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENPORT=8050
    networks:
    - byfn
    volumes:
        - ./artifacts/genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
        - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/base.order/orderers/orderer2.base.order/msp:/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
        - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/base.order/orderers/orderer2.base.order/tls:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls
        - orderer2.base.order:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer
    ports:
    - 8050:8050  

  orderer3.base:
    extends:
      file: base.yaml
      service: orderer-base
    container_name: orderer3.base
    environment:
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENPORT=9050
    networks:
    - byfn
    volumes:
        - ./artifacts/genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
        - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/base.order/orderers/orderer3.base.order/msp:/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
        - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/base.order/orderers/orderer3.base.order/tls:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls
        - orderer3.base.order:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer
    ports:
    - 9050:9050
```

`base.yaml`

```
orderer-base:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:$IMAGE_TAG
    environment:
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=debug
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
      # enabled TLS
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
      - ORDERER_KAFKA_TOPIC_REPLICATIONFACTOR=1
      - ORDERER_KAFKA_VERBOSE=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTCERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTPRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    command: orderer
```

Comment: can you add base.yaml?

Comment: Also, did you generate certificates for orderers 2-3?

Comment: yes added base.yaml

Comment: Please check my answer, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mapping ports uncorrectly.
It must be:

orderer1 `7050:7050`

orderer2 `8050:7050`

orderer3 `9050:7050`

And remove the environment `LISTEN_PORT` from every orderer so that the default is always 7050.
This means that, in case of orderer 2, you are mapping container inner port 7050 to the external 8050.

Also modify in your **configtx.yaml** the same thing, so you will have 3 ports 7050.
Just avoid modifying internal ports for containers, you are free to modify external ones.

Comment: Getting this error `consenter info in etcdraft configuration did not specify host
panic: consenter info in etcdraft configuration did not specify host [recovered]
 panic: consenter info in etcdraft configuration did not specify host` while running your config

Comment: The above exaclty happening on `configtxgen -profile Raft  -channelID $CHANNEL_NAME -outputBlock ./artifacts/genesis.block`

Comment: Have any thoughts on this . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59876137/hyperledger-fabric-peer-update-failed-signature-set-did-not-satisfy-policy

Comment: @SaifAli Yes its fixed

Comment: can you help me with the steps you took to fix it ?

Comment: @SaifAli These are my configuration files  https://github.com/shamonshan/fabric-basic