# Hyperledger Test Network - failed to create new connection: context deadline exceeded

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm trying to create a channel in the test-network in Hyperledger Fabric samples:

```
localhost:~/fabric-samples/test-network$ ./network.sh createChannel
```

but I get this error:

```
Error: failed to create deliver client for orderer: orderer client failed to connect to localhost:7050: failed to create new connection: context deadline exceeded
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Channel creation failed !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Error !!! Create channel failed
```

All containers are running on Docker:

```
localhost:~/fabric-samples/test-network$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                              NAMES
96b7f8e1b2a8        hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest      "peer node start"   5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes        7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9051->9051/tcp   peer0.org2.example.com
79a2c0ac6785        hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest      "peer node start"   5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes        0.0.0.0:7051->7051/tcp             peer0.org1.example.com
f87e809ddaa4        hyperledger/fabric-orderer:latest   "orderer"           5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes        0.0.0.0:7050->7050/tcp             orderer.example.com
```

These are the complete logs if I restart the network and try to create the channel:

```
localhost:~/fabric-samples/test-network$ ./network.sh down
Stopping network

Stopping peer0.org2.example.com ... done
Stopping peer0.org1.example.com ... done
Stopping orderer.example.com    ... done
Removing peer0.org2.example.com ... done
Removing peer0.org1.example.com ... done
Removing orderer.example.com    ... done
Removing network net_test
Removing volume net_orderer.example.com
Removing volume net_peer0.org1.example.com
Removing volume net_peer0.org2.example.com
Removing network net_test
WARNING: Network net_test not found.
Removing volume net_peer0.org3.example.com
WARNING: Volume net_peer0.org3.example.com not found.
---- No containers available for deletion ----
---- No images available for deletion ----
localhost:~/fabric-samples/test-network$ ./network.sh up
Starting nodes with CLI timeout of '5' tries and CLI delay of '3' seconds and using database 'leveldb' with crypto from 'cryptogen'

LOCAL_VERSION=2.1.1
DOCKER_IMAGE_VERSION=2.1.1
/home/daniele/fabric-samples/test-network/../bin/cryptogen

##########################################################
##### Generate certificates using cryptogen tool #########
##########################################################

##########################################################
############ Create Org1 Identities ######################
##########################################################
+ cryptogen generate --config=./organizations/cryptogen/crypto-config-org1.yaml --output=organizations
org1.example.com
+ res=0
+ set +x
##########################################################
############ Create Org2 Identities ######################
##########################################################
+ cryptogen generate --config=./organizations/cryptogen/crypto-config-org2.yaml --output=organizations
org2.example.com
+ res=0
+ set +x
##########################################################
############ Create Orderer Org Identities ###############
##########################################################
+ cryptogen generate --config=./organizations/cryptogen/crypto-config-orderer.yaml --output=organizations
+ res=0
+ set +x

Generate CCP files for Org1 and Org2
/home/daniele/fabric-samples/test-network/../bin/configtxgen
#########  Generating Orderer Genesis block ##############
+ configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis -channelID system-channel -outputBlock ./system-genesis-block/genesis.block
2020-06-24 17:43:43.129 CEST [common.tools.configtxgen] main -> INFO 001 Loading configuration
2020-06-24 17:43:43.249 CEST [common.tools.configtxgen.localconfig] completeInitialization -> INFO 002 Orderer.Addresses unset, setting to [127.0.0.1:7050]
2020-06-24 17:43:43.250 CEST [common.tools.configtxgen.localconfig] completeInitialization -> INFO 003 orderer type: etcdraft
2020-06-24 17:43:43.251 CEST [common.tools.configtxgen.localconfig] completeInitialization -> INFO 004 Orderer.EtcdRaft.Options unset, setting to tick_interval:"500ms" election_tick:10 heartbeat_tick:1 max_inflight_blocks:5 snapshot_interval_size:16777216
2020-06-24 17:43:43.251 CEST [common.tools.configtxgen.localconfig] Load -> INFO 005 Loaded configuration: /home/daniele/fabric-samples/test-network/configtx/configtx.yaml
2020-06-24 17:43:43.257 CEST [common.tools.configtxgen] doOutputBlock -> INFO 006 Generating genesis block
2020-06-24 17:43:43.258 CEST [common.tools.configtxgen] doOutputBlock -> INFO 007 Writing genesis block
+ res=0
+ set +x
Creating network "net_test" with the default driver
Creating volume "net_orderer.example.com" with default driver
Creating volume "net_peer0.org1.example.com" with default driver
Creating volume "net_peer0.org2.example.com" with default driver
Creating orderer.example.com    ... done
Creating peer0.org2.example.com ... done
Creating peer0.org1.example.com ... done
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                  PORTS                              NAMES
6e569adae90d        hyperledger/fabric-orderer:latest   "orderer"           10 seconds ago      Up 4 seconds            0.0.0.0:7050->7050/tcp             orderer.example.com
8cd28fc6db4d        hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest      "peer node start"   10 seconds ago      Up 4 seconds            0.0.0.0:7051->7051/tcp             peer0.org1.example.com
c770ba592a1f        hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest      "peer node start"   10 seconds ago      Up Less than a second   7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9051->9051/tcp   peer0.org2.example.com
localhost:~/fabric-samples/test-network$ ./network.sh createChannel
Creating channel 'mychannel'.

If network is not up, starting nodes with CLI timeout of '5' tries and CLI delay of '3' seconds and using database 'leveldb

### Generating channel create transaction 'mychannel.tx' ###
+ configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel -outputCreateChannelTx ./channel-artifacts/mychannel.tx -channelID mychannel
2020-06-24 17:44:03.617 CEST [common.tools.configtxgen] main -> INFO 001 Loading configuration
2020-06-24 17:44:03.764 CEST [common.tools.configtxgen.localconfig] Load -> INFO 002 Loaded configuration: /home/daniele/fabric-samples/test-network/configtx/configtx.yaml
2020-06-24 17:44:03.765 CEST [common.tools.configtxgen] doOutputChannelCreateTx -> INFO 003 Generating new channel configtx
2020-06-24 17:44:03.774 CEST [common.tools.configtxgen] doOutputChannelCreateTx -> INFO 004 Writing new channel tx
+ res=0
+ set +x

### Generating anchor peer update transactions ###
#######    Generating anchor peer update transaction for Org1MSP  ##########
+ configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel -outputAnchorPeersUpdate ./channel-artifacts/Org1MSPanchors.tx -channelID mychannel -asOrg Org1MSP
2020-06-24 17:44:03.899 CEST [common.tools.configtxgen] main -> INFO 001 Loading configuration
2020-06-24 17:44:04.022 CEST [common.tools.configtxgen.localconfig] Load -> INFO 002 Loaded configuration: /home/daniele/fabric-samples/test-network/configtx/configtx.yaml
2020-06-24 17:44:04.022 CEST [common.tools.configtxgen] doOutputAnchorPeersUpdate -> INFO 003 Generating anchor peer update
2020-06-24 17:44:04.028 CEST [common.tools.configtxgen] doOutputAnchorPeersUpdate -> INFO 004 Writing anchor peer update
+ res=0
+ set +x

#######    Generating anchor peer update transaction for Org2MSP  ##########
+ configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel -outputAnchorPeersUpdate ./channel-artifacts/Org2MSPanchors.tx -channelID mychannel -asOrg Org2MSP
2020-06-24 17:44:04.172 CEST [common.tools.configtxgen] main -> INFO 001 Loading configuration
2020-06-24 17:44:04.322 CEST [common.tools.configtxgen.localconfig] Load -> INFO 002 Loaded configuration: /home/daniele/fabric-samples/test-network/configtx/configtx.yaml
2020-06-24 17:44:04.322 CEST [common.tools.configtxgen] doOutputAnchorPeersUpdate -> INFO 003 Generating anchor peer update
2020-06-24 17:44:04.329 CEST [common.tools.configtxgen] doOutputAnchorPeersUpdate -> INFO 004 Writing anchor peer update
+ res=0
+ set +x

Creating channel mychannel
Using organization 1
+ peer channel create -o localhost:7050 -c mychannel --ordererTLSHostnameOverride orderer.example.com -f ./channel-artifacts/mychannel.tx --outputBlock ./channel-artifacts/mychannel.block --tls --cafile /home/daniele/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
+ res=1
+ set +x
+ peer channel create -o localhost:7050 -c mychannel --ordererTLSHostnameOverride orderer.example.com -f ./channel-artifacts/mychannel.tx --outputBlock ./channel-artifacts/mychannel.block --tls --cafile /home/daniele/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
+ res=1
+ set +x
+ peer channel create -o localhost:7050 -c mychannel --ordererTLSHostnameOverride orderer.example.com -f ./channel-artifacts/mychannel.tx --outputBlock ./channel-artifacts/mychannel.block --tls --cafile /home/daniele/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
+ res=1
+ set +x
+ peer channel create -o localhost:7050 -c mychannel --ordererTLSHostnameOverride orderer.example.com -f ./channel-artifacts/mychannel.tx --outputBlock ./channel-artifacts/mychannel.block --tls --cafile /home/daniele/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
+ res=1
+ set +x
Error: failed to create deliver client for orderer: orderer client failed to connect to localhost:7050: failed to create new connection: context deadline exceeded
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Channel creation failed !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Error !!! Create channel failed
```

These are the logs of the orderer:

```
2020-06-24 15:43:52.494 UTC [localconfig] completeInitialization -> WARN 001 General.GenesisFile should be replaced by General.BootstrapFile
2020-06-24 15:43:52.497 UTC [localconfig] completeInitialization -> INFO 002 Kafka.Version unset, setting to 0.10.2.0
2020-06-24 15:43:52.497 UTC [orderer.common.server] prettyPrintStruct -> INFO 003 Orderer config values:
        General.ListenAddress = "0.0.0.0"
        General.ListenPort = 7050
        General.TLS.Enabled = true
        General.TLS.PrivateKey = "/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key"
        General.TLS.Certificate = "/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt"
        General.TLS.RootCAs = [/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
        General.TLS.ClientAuthRequired = false
        General.TLS.ClientRootCAs = []
        General.Cluster.ListenAddress = ""
        General.Cluster.ListenPort = 0
        General.Cluster.ServerCertificate = ""
        General.Cluster.ServerPrivateKey = ""
        General.Cluster.ClientCertificate = "/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt"
        General.Cluster.ClientPrivateKey = "/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key"
        General.Cluster.RootCAs = [/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
        General.Cluster.DialTimeout = 5s
        General.Cluster.RPCTimeout = 7s
        General.Cluster.ReplicationBufferSize = 20971520
        General.Cluster.ReplicationPullTimeout = 5s
        General.Cluster.ReplicationRetryTimeout = 5s
        General.Cluster.ReplicationBackgroundRefreshInterval = 5m0s
        General.Cluster.ReplicationMaxRetries = 12
        General.Cluster.SendBufferSize = 10
        General.Cluster.CertExpirationWarningThreshold = 168h0m0s
        General.Cluster.TLSHandshakeTimeShift = 0s
        General.Keepalive.ServerMinInterval = 1m0s
        General.Keepalive.ServerInterval = 2h0m0s
        General.Keepalive.ServerTimeout = 20s
        General.ConnectionTimeout = 0s
        General.GenesisMethod = "file"
        General.GenesisFile = "/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block"
        General.BootstrapMethod = "file"
        General.BootstrapFile = "/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block"
        General.Profile.Enabled = false
        General.Profile.Address = "0.0.0.0:6060"
        General.LocalMSPDir = "/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp"
        General.LocalMSPID = "OrdererMSP"
        General.BCCSP.ProviderName = "SW"
        General.BCCSP.SwOpts.SecLevel = 256
        General.BCCSP.SwOpts.HashFamily = "SHA2"
        General.BCCSP.SwOpts.Ephemeral = true
        General.BCCSP.SwOpts.FileKeystore.KeyStorePath = ""
        General.BCCSP.SwOpts.DummyKeystore =
        General.BCCSP.SwOpts.InmemKeystore =
        General.Authentication.TimeWindow = 15m0s
        General.Authentication.NoExpirationChecks = false
        FileLedger.Location = "/var/hyperledger/production/orderer"
        FileLedger.Prefix = "hyperledger-fabric-ordererledger"
        Kafka.Retry.ShortInterval = 5s
        Kafka.Retry.ShortTotal = 10m0s
        Kafka.Retry.LongInterval = 5m0s
        Kafka.Retry.LongTotal = 12h0m0s
        Kafka.Retry.NetworkTimeouts.DialTimeout = 10s
        Kafka.Retry.NetworkTimeouts.ReadTimeout = 10s
        Kafka.Retry.NetworkTimeouts.WriteTimeout = 10s
        Kafka.Retry.Metadata.RetryMax = 3
        Kafka.Retry.Metadata.RetryBackoff = 250ms
        Kafka.Retry.Producer.RetryMax = 3
        Kafka.Retry.Producer.RetryBackoff = 100ms
        Kafka.Retry.Consumer.RetryBackoff = 2s
        Kafka.Verbose = true
        Kafka.Version = 0.10.2.0
        Kafka.TLS.Enabled = false
        Kafka.TLS.PrivateKey = ""
        Kafka.TLS.Certificate = ""
        Kafka.TLS.RootCAs = []
        Kafka.TLS.ClientAuthRequired = false
        Kafka.TLS.ClientRootCAs = []
        Kafka.SASLPlain.Enabled = false
        Kafka.SASLPlain.User = ""
        Kafka.SASLPlain.Password = ""
        Kafka.Topic.ReplicationFactor = 1
        Debug.BroadcastTraceDir = ""
        Debug.DeliverTraceDir = ""
        Consensus = map[SnapDir:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer/etcdraft/snapshot WALDir:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer/etcdraft/wal]
        Operations.ListenAddress = "127.0.0.1:8443"
        Operations.TLS.Enabled = false
        Operations.TLS.PrivateKey = ""
        Operations.TLS.Certificate = ""
        Operations.TLS.RootCAs = []
        Operations.TLS.ClientAuthRequired = false
        Operations.TLS.ClientRootCAs = []
        Metrics.Provider = "disabled"
        Metrics.Statsd.Network = "udp"
        Metrics.Statsd.Address = "127.0.0.1:8125"
        Metrics.Statsd.WriteInterval = 30s
        Metrics.Statsd.Prefix = ""
2020-06-24 15:43:52.534 UTC [orderer.common.server] initializeServerConfig -> INFO 004 Starting orderer with TLS enabled
2020-06-24 15:43:52.547 UTC [fsblkstorage] NewProvider -> INFO 005 Creating new file ledger directory at /var/hyperledger/production/orderer/chains
2020-06-24 15:43:52.571 UTC [orderer.common.server] extractSysChanLastConfig -> INFO 006 Bootstrapping because no existing channels
2020-06-24 15:43:52.590 UTC [orderer.common.server] Main -> INFO 007 Setting up cluster for orderer type etcdraft
2020-06-24 15:43:52.591 UTC [orderer.common.server] reuseListener -> INFO 008 Cluster listener is not configured, defaulting to use the general listener on port 7050
2020-06-24 15:43:52.591 UTC [fsblkstorage] newBlockfileMgr -> INFO 009 Getting block information from block storage
2020-06-24 15:43:52.646 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] HandleChain -> INFO 00a EvictionSuspicion not set, defaulting to 10m0s
2020-06-24 15:43:52.650 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] createOrReadWAL -> INFO 00b No WAL data found, creating new WAL at path '/var/hyperledger/production/orderer/etcdraft/wal/system-channel' channel=system-channel node=1
2020-06-24 15:43:52.656 UTC [orderer.commmon.multichannel] Initialize -> INFO 00c Starting system channel 'system-channel' with genesis block hash 7e6f95c1d82bf6a535276ca517cdde2eeb2d8e99d8182e01c15c7ee43df8d08e and orderer type etcdraft
2020-06-24 15:43:52.658 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] Start -> INFO 00d Starting Raft node channel=system-channel node=1
2020-06-24 15:43:52.659 UTC [orderer.common.cluster] Configure -> INFO 00e Entering, channel: system-channel, nodes: []
2020-06-24 15:43:52.659 UTC [orderer.common.cluster] Configure -> INFO 00f Exiting
2020-06-24 15:43:52.659 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] start -> INFO 010 Starting raft node as part of a new channel channel=system-channel node=1
2020-06-24 15:43:52.660 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] becomeFollower -> INFO 011 1 became follower at term 0 channel=system-channel node=1
2020-06-24 15:43:52.660 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] newRaft -> INFO 012 newRaft 1 [peers: [], term: 0, commit: 0, applied: 0, lastindex: 0, lastterm: 0] channel=system-channel node=1
2020-06-24 15:43:52.660 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] becomeFollower -> INFO 013 1 became follower at term 1 channel=system-channel node=1
2020-06-24 15:43:52.661 UTC [orderer.common.server] Main -> INFO 014 Starting orderer:
 Version: 2.1.1
 Commit SHA: 6393adb
 Go version: go1.14.1
 OS/Arch: linux/amd64
2020-06-24 15:43:52.664 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] run -> INFO 015 This node is picked to start campaign channel=system-channel node=1
2020-06-24 15:43:52.673 UTC [orderer.common.server] Main -> INFO 016 Beginning to serve requests
2020-06-24 15:43:52.674 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] apply -> INFO 017 Applied config change to add node 1, current nodes in channel: [1] channel=system-channel node=1
2020-06-24 15:43:53.674 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] Step -> INFO 018 1 is starting a new election at term 1 channel=system-channel node=1
2020-06-24 15:43:53.674 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] becomePreCandidate -> INFO 019 1 became pre-candidate at term 1 channel=system-channel node=1
2020-06-24 15:43:53.674 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] poll -> INFO 01a 1 received MsgPreVoteResp from 1 at term 1 channel=system-channel node=1
2020-06-24 15:43:53.674 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] becomeCandidate -> INFO 01b 1 became candidate at term 2 channel=system-channel node=1
2020-06-24 15:43:53.674 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] poll -> INFO 01c 1 received MsgVoteResp from 1 at term 2 channel=system-channel node=1
2020-06-24 15:43:53.674 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] becomeLeader -> INFO 01d 1 became leader at term 2 channel=system-channel node=1
2020-06-24 15:43:53.675 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] run -> INFO 01e raft.node: 1 elected leader 1 at term 2 channel=system-channel node=1
2020-06-24 15:43:53.675 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] run -> INFO 01f Leader 1 is present, quit campaign channel=system-channel node=1
2020-06-24 15:43:53.675 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] run -> INFO 020 Raft leader changed: 0 -> 1 channel=system-channel node=1
2020-06-24 15:43:53.676 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] run -> INFO 021 Start accepting requests as Raft leader at block [0] channel=system-channel node=1
```

Somebody can help me solve this problem?

Update: I was able to bypass the problem replacing localhost with the ip of the orderer container in docker subnet (in my case 172.28.0.3), which I found doing:

```
localhost:~/fabric-samples/test-network$ docker inspect orderer.example.com  -f "{{json .NetworkSettings.Networks }}"
{"net_test":{"IPAMConfig":null,"Links":null,"Aliases":["f3fdd48a7076","orderer.example.com"],"NetworkID":"23b404bac1f2961b721d1348ee21d1886268e7094485f4f46b0509133ac4bca2","EndpointID":"b026cba3dc23cb17ba7f3f89f2a776af2447233b1ddb829136e0bc2df34063b9","Gateway":"172.28.0.1","IPAddress":"172.28.0.3","IPPrefixLen":16,"IPv6Gateway":"","GlobalIPv6Address":"","GlobalIPv6PrefixLen":0,"MacAddress":"02:42:ac:1c:00:03","DriverOpts":null}}
```

However since the container exposes port 7050, I should be able to connect to localhost as well, but I can't.
Maybe do I have to change something in docker configuration?

Update 26/06
Logs from monitordocker.sh (I get these errors even before launching createChannel):

```
localhost:~/fabric-samples/test-network$ ./monitordocker.sh net_test
Starting monitoring on all containers on the network net_test
ed8fa674c820feae35c2ec8834a4350aca1c1ac590ba677a766fb14281e4fe31
peer0.org2.example.com|2020-06-26 10:08:57.353 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 04b TLS handshake failed with error remote error: tls: bad certificate server=PeerServer remoteaddress=172.18.0.3:35778
peer0.org2.example.com|2020-06-26 10:08:58.354 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 04c TLS handshake failed with error remote error: tls: bad certificate server=PeerServer remoteaddress=172.18.0.3:35780
peer0.org1.example.com|2020-06-26 10:08:58.430 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 04c TLS handshake failed with error remote error: tls: bad certificate server=PeerServer remoteaddress=172.18.0.4:53408
peer0.org1.example.com|2020-06-26 10:08:59.432 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 04d TLS handshake failed with error remote error: tls: bad certificate server=PeerServer remoteaddress=172.18.0.4:53410
peer0.org2.example.com|2020-06-26 10:08:59.641 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 04d TLS handshake failed with error remote error: tls: bad certificate server=PeerServer remoteaddress=172.18.0.3:35786
peer0.org1.example.com|2020-06-26 10:09:00.351 UTC [gossip.discovery] func1 -> WARN 04e Could not connect to Endpoint: peer0.org2.example.com:9051, InternalEndpoint: peer0.org2.example.com:9051, PKI-ID: <nil>, Metadata:  : context deadline exceeded
peer0.org1.example.com|2020-06-26 10:09:00.915 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 04f TLS handshake failed with error remote error: tls: bad certificate server=PeerServer remoteaddress=172.18.0.4:53414
peer0.org2.example.com|2020-06-26 10:09:01.428 UTC [gossip.discovery] func1 -> WARN 04e Could not connect to Endpoint: peer0.org1.example.com:7051, InternalEndpoint: peer0.org1.example.com:7051, PKI-ID: <nil>, Metadata:  : context deadline exceeded
```

It seems something is wrong with the certificates, but I don't understand what. I downloaded fabric-samples from `https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html`, I thought everything was already there.

Update 30/06: It seems that there is some issue with Alpine. I tried on Ubuntu following all the exact steps and everything works fine, so I think I will just go on using Ubuntu.

Logs after setting log levels to DEBUG:

```
2020-06-28 10:52:13.832 CEST [msp] getMspConfig -> DEBU 0f7 Intermediate certs folder not found at [/home/daniele/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/msp/intermediatecerts]. Skipping. [stat /home/daniele/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/msp/intermediatecerts: no such file or directory]
        2020-06-28 10:52:13.833 CEST [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 0f8 Reading directory /home/daniele/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/msp/tlscacerts
        2020-06-28 10:52:13.834 CEST [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 0f9 Inspecting file /home/daniele/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.org2.example.com-cert.pem
        2020-06-28 10:52:13.835 CEST [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 0fa Reading directory /home/daniele/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/msp/tlsintermediatecerts
        2020-06-28 10:52:13.836 CEST [msp] getMspConfig -> DEBU 0fb TLS intermediate certs folder not found at [/home/daniele/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/msp/tlsintermediatecerts]. Skipping. [stat /home/daniele/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/msp/tlsintermediatecerts: no such file or directory]
        2020-06-28 10:52:13.837 CEST [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 0fc Reading directory /home/daniele/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/msp/crls
        2020-06-28 10:52:13.837 CEST [msp] getMspConfig -> DEBU 0fd crls folder not found at [/home/daniele/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/msp/crls]. Skipping. [stat /home/daniele/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/msp/crls: no such file or directory]
        2020-06-28 10:52:13.839 CEST [msp] getMspConfig -> DEBU 0fe Loading NodeOUs
        2020-06-28 10:52:13.842 CEST [common.tools.configtxgen] doOutputAnchorPeersUpdate -> INFO 0ff Writing anchor peer update
        + res=0
        + set +x
        
        Creating channel mychannel
        Using organization 1
        + peer channel create -o localhost:7050 -c mychannel --ordererTLSHostnameOverride orderer.example.com -f ./channel-artifacts/mychannel.tx --outputBlock ./channel-artifacts/mychannel.block --tls --cafile /home/daniele/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
        + res=1
        + set +x
```

Comment: check `127.0.0.1 localhost` entry is present  in `/etc/hosts` file or not. If its not there then add it.  If this didn't work then please share the orderer logs.

Comment: it is present and if I do `telnet localhost 7050` , I can connect

Comment: your orderer logs are fine too. I'm using `orderer.example.com` instead of `localhost` and mapping `127.0.0.1 orderer.example.com` in /etc/hosts. you can try changing `localhost` by `orderer.example.com`. This is just a hit and trial.

Comment: I tried, but I got the same error:

`Error: failed to create deliver client for orderer: orderer client failed to connect to orderer.example.com:7050: failed to create new connection: context deadline exceeded`

Comment: What about the orderer container? Does it go down?

Comment: @DanieleChirivì you can check whether `localhost` is working with `docker` or not by running a `nginx` container like `docker container run --name nginx -p 80:80 -d nginx` and then try `localhost` in browser. Then it would be clear if it's a docker issue or not. I'm using `docker  for windows` and I can access `nginx` via `localhost` in browser.

Comment: @XhensB the orderer container is running

Comment: @DanieleChirivì I forgot to ask you which OS are you using?

Comment: It's Alpine Linux

Comment: @DanieleChirivì Please try `export DISCOVERY_AS_LOCALHOST=TRUE`.

Comment: Are you running the scripts from within a Docker container as well or are you running them on your host system?

Comment: @alpha I tried, but it doesn't work

Comment: @GariSingh I'm running them on my host system

Comment: Something that came up my mind right now. Do you have the right chmod permissions on the `organizations` directory?

Comment: @DanieleChirivì Can you please share the tls certificate of peer? Is `localhost` present under `SAN`? This is more related to `docker networks`. `172.18.0.3` is `container address`.

Comment: @XhensB Yes, I have the right permissions

Comment: @alpha in which folder can I exactly find it?

Comment: for peers it is `crypto-config/peerOrganizations/beta.com/peers/peer1.beta.com/tls/server.crt` and for orderer it is `crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/alpha.com/orderers/orderer1.alpha.com/tls/server.crt`. change the directories accordingly. Use openssl to check `X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:`.

Comment: Can you access the container via `localhost` for different docker images like nginx? In the above comment section, I have shared the command(`nginx` container command) to test it. Please use it to test whether `localhost` is working or not.

Comment: @alpha yes if I run nginx localhost with docker, I can reach it

Comment: @DanieleChirivì, Can you please try adding `extra_hosts` in `compose.yml` file and map `orderer1.example.com 127.0.0.1`. You can try adding the `container_ip` instead of `127.0.0.1` but the `container_ip` isn't static hecme you have to change it every time.

Answer (score 4):

Interesting.  I went through your logs and I don't see anything obvious, and you've already figured out that you can't reach the orderer . . I want to check if this is indeed a TLS issue.  Can you try something for me please?

- there should be a monitordocker.sh script in `fabric-samples/commercial-paper/organization/digibank/configuration/cli/` folder.  Its logspout and pulls all the logs together, copy that over to test-network.
- bring your network down again.
- bring your network up again
- run `./monitordocker.sh net_test` in a separate terminal
- run `./network.sh createChannel` and see if you get more insight from logspout

Answer (score 0):

Feels like a connection or set up problem, but might need more data to do a RCA.  Could you bring down your network and start it up again, please and share the full log once you kick off createChannel, it Wil start with something like “Creating channel ‘mychannel’.  If network is not up, starting nodes with CLI timeout of ‘5’ tries and CLI delay of ‘3’ seconds and using database ‘leveldb“

```
  ./network.sh down
  ./network.sh up
  ./network.sh createChanel
```

Comment: I shared the complete log

Comment: @DanieleChirivì two more things.  

(1) Could you please share your IT setup, are you running on MAC, Ubuntu, Windows, etc?

(2) Could you take a look at set up your grpc logs to DEBUG to enable further information, please.  FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=grpc=debug might give us more information.
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.0/logging-control.html

Comment: (1) I'm running Fabric on Alpine Linux on a VM (2) I change the log level but I can't share the complete logs, however I see errors about missing certificates like this one: `2020-06-28 10:52:13.836 CEST [msp] getMspConfig -> DEBU 0fb TLS intermediate certs folder not found at [/home/daniele/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/msp/tlsintermediatecerts]. Skipping. [stat /home/daniele/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/msp/tlsintermediatecerts: no such file or directory]`

Comment: @DanieleChirivì when do you get this error, could you provide some logs before and after?  I am trying to find out why it's looking for tlsintermediatecerts in test network, I don't have that directory either and I just set up test-network for myself.

Comment: I shared some logs, I get this error after launching ./network.sh createChannel

Comment: ```Update 30/06: It seems that there is some issue with Alpine. I tried on Ubuntu following all the exact steps and everything works fine, so I think I will just go on using Ubuntu.```

Hmmm! I wonder if Alpine Linux handles TLS certs differently than Ubuntu or other flavors of Linux . . .

Comment: The missing folders are not needed - it's just debug statements.  We don't use intermediate certificates with test network.

Answer (score 0):

@DanieleChirivì I was looking at a [similar issue on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55803125/tls-handshake-failed-with-error-remote-error-tls-bad-certificate-server-ordere) and this might be our issue here, well at least it's worth a shot. Lets try a couple of things,

- Could you go to `test-network/organizations/cryptogen directory`
- update the yaml files for org1 and org2  to add 172.18.0.4 and 172.18.0.3 respectively.

And lets run it again.

Comment: I added in each yaml file under cryptogen the IPs of all the containers, but still doesn't work

Comment: Same errors, or did you see anything different in the logs?

Answer (score 0):

Delete all the docker images, including not used and used, and then re-download them. I did that and it works.